# ROS_PACKAGE_PATH problems

Tags: ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello friends.

I downloaded a folder with some rosbuild type packages.

I'm trying to build the packages, but for that I needed to use the following command:

```
 export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/paulo/Workspace
```

I then made `rosmake name_of_package name_of_package` and I built all of my downloaded packages.

They all build without any errors, what is good. But the problem is the following.

When I try to use roslaunch, ros tells me it can't locate roslaunch. Gives the following error:

```
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1]. 

Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>
```

If I do the `source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash` I can use roslaunch again or it finds the roslaunch pack if I use `rospack find roslaunch` but it forgets about the packages I built.

Anyone knows how I can solve this problem? Like how I can built the packages and keep roslaunch and the rest of ros working?

Thx so much!

p.s.:If you are curious about the folder with packages I downloaded its the following.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlBQLbmc03g

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/102551/ros_package_path-problems/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2013-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH should include your ros_workspace as well as ROS system installed path.

Add this to your .bashrc file so that it executes on every terminal launch 
source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash 
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/paulo/ros_workspace:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

---

Originally posted by [AbhishekMehta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2140/abhishekmehta/) with karma: 226 on 2013-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1